# ServiceWorker not receiving fetch requests

Tags: service-worker

I am installing a service worker for the first time, and following the tutorial at: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/service-workers

My service worker behaves as expected when installing and updating, but fetch requests are not triggered as expected.

```
var CACHE_NAME = 'test-cache-v1'
var urlsToCache = [
  '/',
  '/public/scripts/app.js'
]

self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {
  console.log('Installing new service worker', event)
  // Perform install steps
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
      .then(function (cache) {
        return cache.addAll(urlsToCache)
      })
      .catch(err => console.log('Error Caching', err))
)
})

self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
  console.log('Fetch req', event)
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request)
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log('Cache hit', response)
        // Cache hit - return response
        if (response) {
          return response
        }
        return fetch(event.request)
        .catch(e => console.log('Error matching cache', e))
      }
    )
  )
})
```

I see 'Installing new service worker' outputted to the console when expected, but not 'Fetch req'. I am using Chrome devtools and have accessed the "Inspect" option next to the ServiceWorker under the Application tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**On dynamic websites, be careful!**

If service worker has scope: example.com/weather/
It does not have scope: example.com/weather

Especially on firebase which by default removes trailing slash

In this case, service worker will install, activate, and even cache files, but not receive ‘fetch’ events! Very hard to debug.

Add “trailingSlash”: true to firebase.json under ‘hosting’. This will solve the problem. Make sure to modify rewrite from:

```
  {
    "source": "/weather", "function": "weather"
  }
```

To :

```
  {
    "source": "/weather/", "function": "weather"
  }
```

As well as manifest.json

Comment: Which firebase? What are you talking about?

Answer (score 19):

If you listen for the `activate` event, and add in a call to `clients.claim()` inside that event, then your newly active service worker will take control over existing web pages in its scope, including the page that registered it. There's more information in [this article](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/service-worker/lifecycle#clientsclaim) on the service worker lifecycle. The following code is sufficient:

```
self.addEventListener('activate', () => self.clients.claim());
```

If you don't call `clients.claim()`, then the service worker will activate, but not control any of the currently open pages. It won't be until you navigate to the next page under its scope (or reload a current page) that the service worker will take control, and start intercepting network requests via its `fetch` handler.

Comment: U save my day :)

Answer (score 0):

I found that Jeff Posnick's "clients.claim()" in the activate event handler was useful, but it was not enough to cache resources the *first* time the JS app runs.  That is because on the first run the service worker has not finished activating when the JS starts loading its resources.

The following function lets the main app register the SW and then *waits for it to activate* before continuing to load resources:

```
/**
 * Registers service worker and waits until it is activated or failed.
 * @param js URI of service worker JS
 * @param onReady function to call when service worker is activated or failed
 * @param maxWait maximum time to wait in milliseconds
 */
function registerServiceWorkerAndWaitForActivated(js, onReady, maxWait) {
    let bReady = false;

    function setReady() {
        if (!bReady) {
            bReady = true;
            onReady();
        }
    }

    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        setTimeout(setReady, maxWait || 1000);
        navigator.serviceWorker.register(js).then((reg) => {
            let serviceWorker = reg.installing || reg.waiting;
            if (serviceWorker) {
                serviceWorker.addEventListener("statechange", (e) => {
                    if (serviceWorker.state == "activated")
                        setReady();
                });
            } else {
                if (!reg.active)
                    console.log("Unknown service worker state");
                setReady();
            }
        }, () => setReady());
    } else {
        let msg = "ServiceWorker not available.  App will not run offline."
        if (document.location.protocol != "https:")
            msg = "Please use HTTPS so app can run offline later.";
        console.warn(msg);
        alert(msg);
        setReady();
    }
}
```